# Get username and first name via Telegram Bot API with available matching phone number

Tags: php, api, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a list of phone numbers.

I need their matching `username` and `first_name` in Telegram(if they subscribed to Telegram).

I want to get these info(username and first_name) with Telegram BOT API.

Is it possible? How can I do this? (with PHP)

This is my sample code:

```
<?php

//telegram sdk and configuration
$client = new Zelenin\Telegram\Bot\Api('someRandomToken');

$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

//your app
try {

    if($update->message->text != '/next_event_datetime')
        exit;

    $dom = Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser::file_get_html('http://laratalks.com/');
    $element = $dom->find('#location header.section-header h3', 0);
    $dateTime = $element->plaintext;

    $response = $client->sendMessage([
        'chat_id' => $update->message->chat->id,
        'text' => $dateTime
    ]);

} catch (\Zelenin\Telegram\Bot\NotOkException $e) {

    //echo error message ot log it
    //echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

Comment: It was better to not mention your sample code because it doesnt in relation with your question parts

Comment: Think about it... would you want someone who just has your phone number to be able to get your name and username? It'd be a privacy violation, and a serious potential start to someone who wants to do a phishing attack on you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can get the username and `user_id` from a user when you have the phone number. I don't know of any way to get the first name.

Just send a contact (`sendContact`) with any first_name and the phone number. Telegram responds with the sent contact, which includes the `user_id` (if the user has Telegram) and `username` if the user has set one.

Step by step:

1. Send a contact with the number and and any first name to any chat (yourself, a group, doesn't matter...)
2. The Telegram API will respond with the send message or some error code. If the message was sent successful, the contact in the response may have more details (username and user_id).

Comment: Due to [Telegram Bot Doc](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendcontact) method (`sendContact`) is for send an existing contact (for example person A contact number) to person B. Wholly different thing from this question

Comment: Try it yourself. Let the bot send a contact and look at the resulting message.

Comment: I made a test bot to test some of the api [here](http://telegram.me/JohannesTestBot). Send it a message like `/raw sendContact phone_number 424314159 first_name bot_support` and it will answer with the (slightly parsed) JSON result. Note that there is a `user_id` field.

Comment: Your bot is this: you send a `phone_number` with ARBITRARY `user_id`. Then if that phone number is subscribed to telegram, your bot shows a `add contact` message with that ARBITRARY `user_name`. It is like adding a phone number to my cell phone phonebook with my given name and NOT users real user_name. Check yourself. Also these are provided for client not bot( to add contact)

Comment: when i add a contact with phone number in android app.
telegram show me the contact's username.is it possible in api?

Comment: @TickTock One part of the question is: can a bot get the username (if any) given the phone number. The answer from telegram when sending a contact with that number contains that information.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn ,Would you please, send some JSON responses from telegram containing these data?

Answer (score 0):

In short words it is **IMPOSSIBLE**. But read whole post, it may be useful for you.

Getting phone number from Telegram and via Telegram Bot API is one-way,
that means you can NOT send phone number and get users data from telegram.(Note: We assume you do not added users by phone number before)

There is only two ways to get users phone number in telegram:

> 1- Get it with specific [`KeyboardButton`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton) button. In this way Telegram sends users phone number after user accepted .( Note: User MUST be your Bot subscriber before)
>
> 2- Ask user him/her phone number, but it is not reliable and you should check it with other ways(like SMS approve and so on)

after all, although these two ways can be used to grab user's phone number but when you grab phone number you have, so your list is not useful.

BUT you want to grab `username` with phone number available,this is IMPOSSIBLE due to Telegram Bot API infrastructur .